# Hide/black window from screen Shares in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a c# windows forms application that displays sensitive data.

I saw something on Amazon Prime Video (in browser) that I want to build into my app. If you try to record or share a series or movie, it will only share a black window, but you can still see the movie on the screen.

Is there a way to hide / black the application for screenshares/screenrecordings?

If there is a way, is there a way to enable or disable it using a button?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity)

Comment: How are you going to prevent someone from recording it with their phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

Using [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) it works. Thanks to Jimi for giving the hint.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hwnd, uint dwAffinity);
```

Add this in the "on_Load" method or form constructor:

```
SetWindowDisplayAffinity(this.Handle, 1);
```

Using Systems:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```